# Spnego keytab authentication in Tomcat on Windows Server fails

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-security, kerberos, spnego

I am testing the Spengo API on a Tomcat 6 server. The file I am calling in my browser is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello SPNEGO Example</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello <%= request.getRemoteUser() %> !
</body>
</html>
```

I added spnego-r7.jar to my %TOMCAT_HOME%\lib and the following filters to my %TOMCAT_HOME%\conf\web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.basic</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.localhost</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.allow.unsecure.basic</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.client.module</param-name>
        <param-value>spnego-client</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.krb5.conf</param-name>
        <param-value>krb5.conf</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.conf</param-name>
        <param-value>login.conf</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.preauth.username</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.preauth.password</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.login.server.module</param-name>
        <param-value>spnego-server</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.prompt.ntlm</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>spnego.logger.level</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpnegoHttpFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In %TOMCAT_HOME% is a krb5.conf, a login.conf and sys-spn.keytab.

The sys-spn.keytab is tested with a standalone java program and works correctly.

The krb5.conf is as follows:

```
[libdefaults]
    default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac
    default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac
    permitted_enctypes   = rc4-hmac
    default_realm        = TEST.LOCAL

[realms]
    TEST.LOCAL  = {
        kdc = dc2.test.local 
        default_domain = TEST.LOCAL 
}

[domain_realm]
    .TEST.LOCAL = TEST.LOCAL
```

My login.conf is as follows:

```
spnego-client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};

spnego-server {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    storeKey=true
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="C:/sys-spn.keytab"
    principal="HTTP/as1.test.local@TEST.LOCAL";
};
```

DC2 is my KDC and AS1 is my application server. When I call the hello_spnego.jsp from a webbrowser not using the keytab (login and pass for SPN) the handshake is correct and I get Hello ! When I don't use login and pass but the keytab file I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
KrbException: Specified version of key is not available (44)
    at sun.security.krb5.EncryptionKey.findKey(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.krb5.KrbApReq.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.InitSecContextToken.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Context.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.GSS_acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.spnego.SpNegoContext.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jgss.GSSContextImpl.acceptSecContext(Unknown Source)
    at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.doSpnegoAuth(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:444)
    at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:283)
    at net.sourceforge.spnego.SpnegoHttpFilter.doFilter(SpnegoHttpFilter.java:229)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What could be my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My keytab file had a wrong KVNO. Tip: Always regenerate your keytab file if in doubt!